# get_results return doesn't iterate

Tags: wordpress

I am creating WP plugin,here is my code

```
$cmdb = new wpdb(DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);  
    $retval = '';  

    echo '<table align="center">';
    echo '<th>Coupon ID</td>';
    echo '<th>Coupon Name</td>';
       echo '<th>Coupon Text</td>';
    echo '<th>Please Select Order</td>';

            $coupon_count = $cmdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM coupons");  
            var_dump($product_count);

        foreach($coupon_count as $cc)
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<input type="label" value="'.$cc->id.'"';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$cc->title.'"';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$cc->subtitle.'"';
echo '<select></select>';

echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

but the output is ![enter image description here][1]
I dont know why it is not showing me remaining stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb) wrong. Don't make your own var use the one WordPress has.

```
global $wpdb;
$coupon_count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM coupons");
```

Also Tables in WordPress need to be prefixed.